# Activity indicator not in centre

Tags: ios, swift, activity-indicator

I have 1 activity indicator on my login screen.  When the user presses the login button it runs:

```
// Start the activity indicator.
    activityInd.center = view.center
    activityInd.startAnimating()
```

when the user presses the guest login button it runs:

```
// Start the activity indicator.
    activityInd.center = view.center
    activityInd.startAnimating()
```

When the user presses the login button the activity indicator is centered and displays as required.

However, when the user presses the guest button the activity indicator is not centered?

Both the same code for the same activity indicator.

If anyone knows why this happens I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Centering views this way is incorrect in the first place. Instead of `view.center`, you should be using half of the superview width and height. Also, if you are using autoresizing, then autoresizing mask must be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : 
activityInd.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);

Setup your autoresizing mask if you support rotation.
activityInd.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

hope this helps you...